# Xcode - binary file is not permitted while adding private pod

Tags: flutter, xcode, cocoapods, testflight

I'm not a swift developer So I am sorry in advance if this question is too trivial:

I have an application where I added private pods library (according to [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) tutorial)

Then I added to ma Podfile

```
source 'path/to/private/pods/repository'
pod 'HigoSDK.precompiled'
```

This how my SDK looks "Pods" section in XCode:

[image]

I am able to use classes from this SDK in code but when I try to to publish app to testflight I get following error: [image]

I checked archive files and indeed my HigoSDK is there but I have no idea how to remove it
In BuildPhases I make sure that my HigoSDK is NOT in the embed frameworks or link binary with libraries

My app is made with flutter but I don't think its matter since I'm focusing only on ios side rn.